# Selecting text from an external html file - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I load html code into a div by clicking on the link:

```
$( "#test1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#anothertest" ).load( "./templates/test1.html" );
});
```

The following Jquery code works if it is within the same html document (but as I am loading some extra code into the div from an external code it does not work):

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
  var doc = document;
  var element = this[0];
  console.log(this, element);
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();        
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  };


$("#select-button").click(function() {
  $(".testcont").selectText();
});
```

the external html file code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>


<div class="testcont">some text to be selected</div>
<br>
<button type="button" id="select-button">Select Text</button>
```

Can this somehow be done?

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: learn about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading new content, you need to [delegate the events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$("body").on("click", "#select-button", function() {
  $(".testcont").selectText();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply :).